# Using custom claims in trust policy for `sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-iam, openid-connect

I have a GitLab pipeline that access AWS resources by assuming a role using OpenID Connect (`sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity`).

I can use the `sub` claim to restrict the policy to a specific project and branch/tag. This is the format used by GitLab: `project_path:{group}/{project}:ref_type:{type}:ref:{branch_name}`

I want to also use the `environment` [custom claim](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/id_token_authentication.html#token-payload) included in the JWT payload as a condition for the trust policy of the role.

I have `https://gitlab.com` configured as an OIDC identity provider.

This is the trust policy that I have working now:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:sub": "project_path:my-group/my-project:ref_type:branch:ref:main"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to use something like this:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": "arn:aws:iam::0123456789:oidc-provider/gitlab.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "gitlab.com:sub": "project_path:my-group/my-project:ref_type:branch:ref:main",
                    "gitlab.com:environment": "production"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to use custom claims in the trust policy?